# Integral of the function $\sqrt{|y^2-x|}$ on the domain $x^2\le y\le2$, $|x|\le1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve this:

> Find $\iint\sqrt{|y^2-x|}dxdy$ over $D$, where $D=${$(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2| x^2\le y\le2$ and $|x|\le1$}

by using absolute value definition and checking the region D I get to this:

$\iint\sqrt{|y^2-x|}dxdy$ $= $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{X^2} \sqrt{y^2-x} \,dy\,dx$ $+ $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{X^2}^{2} \sqrt{x-y^2} \,dy\,dx$$

Here's where I get stuck, I don't see what kind of change I should do. 
Any hint would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The domain $D$ is a filled out U of width $2$ whose arc is parabolic. In addition the analytic representation of the integrand is not constant throughout $D$: There is a "byte" in the south-east part of $D$ where a different regime is in force. The correct setup would be as follows:
$$J=\int_{-1}^0\int_{x^2}^2\sqrt{y^2-x}\>dy\>dx+\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{x}}^2\sqrt{y^2-x}\>dy\>dx+\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x-y^2}\>dy\>dx\ .$$